# How to get coordinates between two anchors - illustrator, script

Tags: adobe-illustrator, extendscript

Is there any way to get coordinates on the line in my script for Adobe Illustrator?

I have line (or any rounded curve) with anchors [X, Y]: [10, 20] and [50, 100] and I want to get coordinates on the line between the anchors. I want coordinates for X = 30, but is there any way how to get Y value?

Answer (score 0):

This should be your solution for a line:

```
var calc_distance = function(x1,x2){
    return (x1 > x2) ? x1 - x2 : x2 - x1; 
    }

var p1 = {x:10,y:20};
var p2 = {x:50,y:100};
var p3 = {x:30,y:null};

var d = calc_distance(p1.x, p2.x); // calc whole distance
var d1 = calc_distance(p1.x, p3.x); // calc distance to p3
var blend = ((100/d) * d1) / 100;// percentual value between p1 and p2

var y = p1.y + blend * (p2.y - p1.y);
p3.y = y;
```